# React-Native app not installing in Android (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I am completely new to mobile programming and this week installed React-Native and Android Studio in my virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Next, I created the "Hello World" app with Android studio, enabled USB Debugging on my Android 5 phone and it ran ok. Finally, I started with React-native ("AwesomeApp") but I get this error:

```
...
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Aquaris E5 HD - 5.0'
01:06:03 E/1659110437: Error while uploading app-debug.apk : Unknown failure
Unable to install /home/osboxes/React/AwesomeProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unable to upload some APKs
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:920)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:113)

[...]

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unable to upload some APKs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 39.701 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
```

I have searched on different sites but cannot solve it.

Platforms installed: Android 23, 24
Build-Tools installed: 23.0.1, 23.0.3, 24.0.3

Comment: Just for testing reasons, can you try that? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html and then if it works, you can go back to your case. At least generating a new apk should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2720) on RN's Github repo where people have the same issue. Looks like the solution that worked for most of the people was to downgrade the gradle plugin version to 1.2.3. Try changing it in the top-level build.gradle file (`AwesomeApp/android/build.gradle`) of your Android project:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'  

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Other solutions suggest that the device might not have sufficient memory. Try deleting 1-2 apps and then install your AwesomeApp again.

Finally, some people upvoted a solution that suggests running the following commands before `react-native run-android`. To me this doesn't seem related to the problem, though.

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
react-native start
```

Comment: downgrading the gradle plugin version to 1.2.3 it worked with me